# Data task in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have huge data set (thousand record rows) in Excel (columns -monthes, customers, expenditures). I have to find those customers who spend at least, let's say 100 USD, in **each** month.

Is there any fast way for solution? I have tried pivot table, but without success. Maybe I should upload data set to Access then run query? Any ideas?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFLDf.png)

Comment: From your brief description, Access will be more suitable than Excel.

Comment: Can you post a small sample table of what your data looks like? Especially how the dates are given. Curious because depending on how its laid out, it can be a quick thing or perhaps more involved

Comment: Also, by "each month", you mean individual month yeah? Not that they spent 100 in each month for the year (meaning 100 in Jan, Feb, Mar, ..., Dec)?

Comment: Hi, I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Hm, it's trickier than I thought. Do you mind setting up a spreadsheet once (with many formulas and a helper column or two), then using a worksheet to pull the data? I'm getting closer to a solution but it's a little involved (but nothing insane, just some helper columns and mix of formulas). Or, is VBA an option?

Comment: I have managed to solve. I have setup a pivot with periods in column (layout like in Scott Holtzman example). Copied data from pvt as values to new ws and added a column with formula COUNTIF(rng; cell value >=100). It gives a number of month where a condition is met (I know max number of month). Not a pretty solution, but under given time constrain it is OK for me. It would interesting to see Access solution which I believe should staightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that you could make a pivot with rows as customers, columns as months, values as Sum of Expenditure. From this, add a normal column formula at the end that has the `MIN` of the customer's monthly expenditure columns (make sure the references are just to cell address, not the `GETPIVOTDATA` reference). Because of blanks in the values, you might need to use an array version of the MIN (e.g. `=MIN(--(B2:M2))` and enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather than just Enter). Filtering your MIN to be above your limit gets you your customers.

If you are going to have to do this often though, access may well be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column with your pivot table.

Formula for D2 = `=IF(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$19,$B$2:$B$19,B2,$A$2:$A$19,A2)>100,"Y","")`

[image]

An access query is a good option, but sometimes its too much work for just a one off need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Is it possible to elimate other customers that do not mmet criteria, in your example, I want like to see only b customers in pivot as he has at least 100 USD exp. in 3 months?

Comment: Just curiuos, how SQL query solution would like in Access?

Comment: sorry, I missed the **each month** requirement. I have to run out now, but it can be done easily with a multiple step process. Will play with it tomorrow if you haven't solved already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which I think you're trying to get.

Say your Customer Name is in column C, and their amount spent is in D.  You can use an array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) that will return the list of names where the spending is over $100:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C$4,SMALL(IF(D$1:D$4>100,ROW(C$1:C$4)-ROW(C$1)+1),ROWS(C$1:C1))),"")`

[image]

Just adjust ranges as necessary, enter in A1 (as array) and drag down.

You can put this formula in a new workbook, using the references to the "data workbook", and then it'll keep a populated list of those users who spent over 100.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - that's what I get trying to help folks out in between a busy work day. :P Sorry OP, I'll see if I can tweak this for Month.